# Crop image to the size of a div. Overflow: hidden doesn't work

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create an image gallery by using Bootstrap grid layout. The whole gallery shall have 100% width. I made a row with two grids. Each of them includes one picture. The picture from the first grid decides about the height. The picture in the second grid shall have the same height as the picture in the first grid and be cropped right and left.

See the code below.

My problem is that the second picture is bigger than the div.

I tried around using `overflow: hidden` and `position: absolute`, it has the right height but it's not cropped.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
}

secondimage {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.heighthundred {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="linknews" class="cointainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="image">
        <div class="">
          <img src="./image1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="secondimage">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="./image2.jpg" class="heighthundred">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Remember to put a `.` before your `secondimage`  class name in your CSS code.

Comment: I played around with dev tools on the link you provided. A solution that worked for me (though I'm not sure how practical it is overall) was to give the news-image (`class="bla"`) a width of 100%. Then I added `overflow-x: hidden` to the `body`. This does shrink the image horizontally a bit, instead of cropping it though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-4 padzero"> replace this from below line.

<div class="col-sm-4 padzero" style="overflow: hidden;">
```

or

Put CSS code in your CSS.

```
.col-sm-4.padzero{
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't really understand why but that works great :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as the `background-image` to your `div`

So your html becomes :-

```
 <div class="image">
    <div style="background-image: url('./image2.jpg');">
    </div>
  </div>
```

and in your css

```
.image > div{
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

and you won't need the second-image class now.

Answer (score -1):

You should add position: relative; on secondimage class.

```
secondimage{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but now there's just a white field having the right size but no image.

Comment: Do you live demo? Because i have tried its working.